# How do I access this damn textArea?

Tags: java, jframe, textarea, textfield

Okay, here's the class I'm working with.

The issue is within the write() method, where I'm thrown a NPE... I don't understand how to access this text area, I just want to simply add text to the end of it!

```
public class chatBox extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    protected static JTextField textField;
    protected static JTextArea textArea;
    private final static String newline = "\n";
    public static int tick = 0;

    public chatBox() {
        super(new GridBagLayout());

        textField = new JTextField(25);
        textField.addActionListener(this);

        textArea = new JTextArea(5, 25);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        //Add Components to this panel.
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.weighty = 0.5;
        c.weightx = 0.5;

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        add(textField, c);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.weightx = 0;
        c.weighty = 0.1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;

        add(scrollPane, c);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        String text = textField.getText();

        textArea.append(Commands.cmd(text) + newline);
        textField.selectAll();

        //Make sure the new text is visible, even if there
        //was a selection in the text area.
        //textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
    }

    public static void write(String wstr) {

        System.out.println("Writing " + wstr);
        textArea.append(wstr + newline);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `chatBox` object in order to `textArea` to be initialized. After that you can call the static method write.

Or you can initialize the static attributes in a static block:

```
static {
    textArea = ....
}
```